# Handle angle bracket in pre tag using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

I have a string like this

```
html = "<pre>City_<cityname>_001</pre>"
```

While trying to parse this using BeautifulSoup 4, using the following code,

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> html = "<pre>City_<cityname>_001</pre>"
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
>>> soup
<pre>City_<cityname>_001</cityname></pre>
>>> soup.text
City__001
```

As can be seen, BeautifulSoup treats `cityname` as a new tag.

Is there any way in which this could be avoided to get the correct text and html?

Comment: so what would your desired output be with this example?

Comment: The desired output is `City_<cityname>_001`.

Answer (score 3):

Comments are ignored by parsers. You could make the content of `<pre>` a comment before parsing and then [extract()](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#extract) the comment later.

```
import bs4
html = "<pre>City_<cityname>_001</pre>"
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(html.replace("<pre>","<pre><!--").replace("</pre>","--></pre>"), "lxml")
pre=soup.find('pre')
pre_comment=pre.find(text=lambda text: isinstance(text, bs4.Comment)).extract()
print(pre_comment)
```

Output:

```
City_<cityname>_001
```

Answer (score 1):

It is a bit of a hack, but you can replace strings wrapped with brackets and then format the string with the results after:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
html = "<pre>City_<cityname>_001</pre>"
_html, _vals = re.sub('(?<=_)\<\w+\>(?=_)', '{}', html), re.findall('(?<=_)\<\w+\>(?=_)', html)
new_result = soup(_html, 'html.parser').find('pre').text.format(*_vals)
```

Output:

```
'City_<cityname>_001'
```