# Adding chevrons and underscores with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, hugo, hugo-shortcode

I want BeautifulSoup to add the strings like this into my HTML pages:

```
{{< Transfer/component_short_name  >}}
```

(If you are interested why, this is a Hugo shortcode, a kind of variable for markdown)

when I build it programmatically in python and add it using `tag.insert_after()`, what ends up in the document looks like this:

```
{{&lt; Transfer/component\_short\_name  &gt;}}
```

which of course does not work the same.

I managed a workaround for the chevrons > < using string replaces, but the underscores '_' would require going into regex, leaving complicated code for a simple operation, so I'm wondering whether there's an option in BeautifulSoup.

I tried various approaches, such as `var_name = var_name.replace("\\_", "_")` , but that does not work.

Comment: Could you insert as comments then remove? https://stackoverflow.com/a/54318271/

Comment: I don't see the `\_` escaping, can you add a short example?  Which soup parser are you using?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a way to avoid the `&lt;` and `&gt;` conversion using BeautifulSoup, but as you say they could be converted afterwards. In the following example there is no underscore escaping:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

shortcode = "{{< Transfer/component_short_name  >}}"
html = "<html><body><h1>hello world</h1></body>"
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
soup.h1.insert_after(shortcode)
fixed = re.sub('\{\{&lt;|&gt;\}\}|\\\_', lambda x: {'{{&lt;' : '{{<', '&gt;}}' : '>}}', '\\_' : '_'}[x.group(0)], str(soup))

print(fixed)
```

Giving the HTML as:

```
<html><body><h1>hello world</h1>{{< Transfer/component_short_name  >}}</body></html>
```

Here, the `\_` replacement does not appear to be needed but I have included it for completeness.